# Fastest and pythonic way of deletion of objects in this code

Tags: python

This is a sample code of what I want to do...

```
class A():
number = 0
List = []
for i in range(5):
    state = A()
    state.number = i
    List.append(state)
print List
Numbers = [1,2,3]
```

Now I want to delete class objects in List whose `number` is in `Numbers`. What is the fastest way to do it ? Also if someone can suggest a more pythonic way of doing this than by  simply creating two `for` loops one for that of `Numbers` and other of `List` and then removing from the `List`.

Comment: `Numbers` is a list of ints. You are assigning an individual int to the `.number` of each element in List. A list of numbers is never going to be the same as an individual number. Did you mean "...whose `number` is in `Numbers`"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of, instead of having a class variable like `A.number` as in:

```
class A():
    number = 0
```

you should generally write a `__init__` method that sets the `number` only on the instance.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
```

Now the rest of your code can be written simply as:

```
List = [A(i) for i in range(5)]
print List
```

To efficiently find items (without two loops) you need sets:

```
Numbers = set([1,2,3])
```

`x in Numbers` now takes constant time. Otherwise Python would have to loop through the List to find a number.

The result you want looks like:

```
filtered = [a for a in List if a.number in Numbers]
```

Comment: @user506710 Yes if you do not use the self prefix.

Comment: @user506710: Yes, anything you write on the `class` level is shared between all instances. For example, all the methods are shared, which is exactly what you'd expect from a class. But when you want to store something on a *instance* of a class, you need to write a method. In this case, the initialisation method `__init__` takes the instance that is passed into this method as `self` and stores the `number` on it.

Comment: @THC4k: `number` is not shared between all instances: http://codepad.org/r9itOCcK. `(instance).number` will just set the `number` property. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects): *By definition, all attributes of a class that are function objects define corresponding methods of its instances.* If an attribute is not a function it will not be defined on the instance.

Comment: @THC4k For this output I was always using class A() because it still worked.... Please explain if each instance has different number how are you saying that number would be shared with all instances of A

Comment: @user506710: Sorry, i messed that up, read Felix' comment for the details. Basically, the code you had has the same effect, for different reasons: First `number` is a shared class variable on `A`. But when you do `A().number=i`, a *new* variable (by the same name) is added to the instance. So there is nothing shared in the end. I still think you should write a `__init__` method though, if only to avoid having to think about this after all.

Answer (score 3):

Using List Comprehension,

NewList=[x for x in List if x.number not in Numbers]

Comment: That is what I was about to suggest. Very pythonic imo, reminds me of some LINQ expressions I've seen

Answer (score 2):

How about [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter)?

```
List = filter(lambda x: x.number not in Numbers, List)
```

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]`

It would be even better if you define `Numbers` as a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).